# Assigning QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer Spectral Ramp to MultiPolygon

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, color-ramp, categorized-renderer

I currently have a Python script that adds a MultiPolygon shapefile to my map within QGIS. Within QGIS, I can apply a categorized symbology render, with the color ramp 'Spectral' going from blue to red, with 55% opacity, for a shapefile called 'Shapefile'. The values within the file under the field 'Intensity' are applied within the categorized symbology (see screenshots). However, I would like to apply this within the Python console. Is there any way I can do this?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: Using the code suggested below, I have this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the code snippet below in the Python console:

```py
default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp('Spectral') #Spectral color ramp
color_ramp.invert()

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Shapefile')[0]
field_index = layer.fields().lookupField('Intensity')
unique_values = list(layer.uniqueValues(field_index))
categories = []
for value in sorted(unique_values):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategory(value, symbol, str(value))
    categories.append(category)
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('Intensity', categories) 
renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)

# If you really want 4 decimal places (as in your screenshot) uncomment the 3 lines below
#labels = ['1.5000','1.6000','1.8000','2.0000','2.2000','2.4000','2.6000','2.8000','3.0000','3.2000','3.3000']
#for i, n in enumerate(labels):
#    renderer.updateCategoryLabel(i, n)
    
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.setOpacity(0.55)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Example result:

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your answer. This has nearly answered my question! However, when it is printed out, the values are not in ascending order, so they have varying colours. I have included a screenshot of what I mean above. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: @LiamHems, Yes- sorting the list of unique values should fix it. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It was greatly appreciated and it works perfectly, exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!