# QGIS layer styling, "symbology" - automate delete and reclassify

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, pyqgis-3, reclassify

My QGIS projects always have around 20 layers that need to be Categorized by a certain value every day. Right now, I need to manually hit the "delete" and "classify" buttons. Fine for a while, but tiresome after 6 months, I want to automate this process but don't know where to start. Could you give me some insight?
[image: Symbology-LayerConfigured]

Comment: Can you provide example data and describe how the data changes? Are the changes random, or within a certain range? Are the values numeric, or strings?

Comment: It has a fixed range and values. The data is a string. Example data is like:

**ID |  << Something in between>> | Validation data.**

The Validation data changes daily after fixing/improving the previous one.

Comment: That's not really example data, since we still don't know, how the validation looks like. If you had integers ranging from 1 to 10 you simply could classify once for those 10 classes and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the field name of the layers is the same you can create a list of the 20 layers you have to update and use this script of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388011/167243) by @Ben W like this :

```py
    field_name = "name_of_your_field"
    layers_name = ["layer_name1", "layer_name2", "layer_name3"]
    for layer_name in layers_name:
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
        field_index = layer.fields().lookupField(field_name)
        unique_values = list(layer.uniqueValues(field_index))
        categories = []
        for value in sorted(unique_values):
            symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
            category = QgsRendererCategory(value, symbol, str(value))
            categories.append(category)
        renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(field_name, categories) 
    
            
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

If the field name is different you can create a dictionary like this :

```py
    layers_fields_name = {"layer_name1":"field_name1", "layer_name2":"field_name2", "layer_name3":"field_name3"}
    for layer_name in layers_fields_name:
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
        field_name = layers_fields_name[layer_name]
        field_index = layer.fields().lookupField(field_name)
        unique_values = list(layer.uniqueValues(field_index))
        categories = []
        for value in sorted(unique_values):
            symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
            category = QgsRendererCategory(value, symbol, str(value))
            categories.append(category)
        renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(field_name, categories) 
    
            
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Every time you launch the script, the style is deleted, recreated and applied to your layers.